# How to code a 3d graph of a cylinder. I tried a code previously suggested but it did not work as intended

Tags: graphs

I'm trying to code a cylinder of the form x^2+y^2=r^2 where h is the unknown height of the cylinder (I want it labeled as r on the axis) because in the problem the radius of the cylinder isn't given and also isn't relevant. I'm trying to have it be in the right corner of my page and then have writing next to it if possible. Any ideas on how I would do this?
Here is a rough sketch of what I'm looking for:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a picture of your intended figure?

Comment: I tried my best to draw out the intended figure. Let me know if it makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [3dtools](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=110,theta=70},line join = round, line cap = round,c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},
    declare function={R=3;h=3;}]
    \path (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
    (0,0,h) coordinate (O');
    \path[save named path=ox] (-R-1,0,0) -- (R+ 3,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \path [save named path=oy] (0,-R-2,0) -- (0,R+2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \path [save named path=oz] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,h+2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \path [save named path=oz'] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-h);
    \path [3d/visible/.style={save named path=cyc,draw={none}}] pic{3d/frustum={R=R,r=R,h=h}};
    \draw[3d/hidden,blue] (O) -- (O');
    \draw[3d/visible, - latex,blue] (O') -- (0,0,h+2);
    \tikzset{3d/ordered paths/.cd,ox/.style={blue,- latex},oy/.style={blue,- latex},oz'/.style={blue}}
    \tikzset{3d/draw ordered paths={ox,oy,oz',cyc}}
    %\path foreach \p/\g in {O/-90}{(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I add some nodes

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=110,theta=70},line join = round, line cap = round,c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},
        declare function={R=3;h=3;}]
        \path (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
        (0,0,h) coordinate (O');
        \path[save named path=ox] (-R-1,0,0) -- (R+ 3,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
        \path [save named path=oy] (0,-R-2,0) -- (0,R+2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
        \path [save named path=oz] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,h+2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
        \path [save named path=oz'] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-h);
        \path [3d/visible/.style={save named path=cyc,draw={none}}] pic{3d/frustum={R=R,r=R,h=h}};
        \draw[3d/hidden,blue] (O) -- (O');
\node[below] at (0,R,0) {$ r $};
\node[below] at (0,-R,0) {$ -r $};
\node[right] at (0,0,h) {$ h $};
        \draw[3d/visible, - latex,blue] (O') -- (0,0,h+2);
        \tikzset{3d/ordered paths/.cd,ox/.style={blue,- latex},oy/.style={blue,- latex},oz'/.style={blue}}
        \tikzset{3d/draw ordered paths={ox,oy,oz',cyc}}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to label h and r in the way I labeled them in the picture?

Comment: When I input the code it doesnt work. I edited my original post so it contains the image i get when I put in the code you gave me.

Comment: You copy file `tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex` from [here](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools/blob/master/tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex) and save with name `tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex` at the same folder of file that you want to compile.

Comment: Sorry, I'm sure if I understand. When I click that link you sent I don't know what to do next. Here I screenshotted my screen and uploaded the image in my original post. Could you please explain it a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: You press "Go to file" and download `tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex` file. and save with name tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex at the same folder of file that you want to compile.

Comment: Well to go to file, I see who options. Which one do I download? (image provided)

Comment: Your question is closed. Please read my comment carefully. There are three files. I said you download `tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex` file and save with name tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex at the same folder of file that you want to compile.

Answer (score 1):

This might help as a start:
coordinate system with pgfplot
cylinder as node with tikz

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  view={25}{15},
  axis lines=center,
  width=20cm,height=20cm,
  xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5,zmin=-5,zmax=5,
  xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},zlabel={$z$},
]

\node[cylinder,draw=black,thick,aspect=0.9,minimum height=1.2cm,minimum width=1cm,shape border rotate=90,fill=white] at (axis cs:0,0,0.25) {};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]